# Combine two services?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, service

I have a service with a timer in the background. This timer executes a certain task after 20 seconds pass. I want the **same** timer to execute **another** task, but in a different amount of seconds. This would be easy by launching both services at the same time, but I am trying to learn how I can do it this other way.

I tried this, but it isn't showing up:

```
 cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.v(TAG, /*"Time remaining " +*/ (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " seconds left");


                if(millisUntilFinished / 10000 == 0){ //TEN SECONDS
                    Log.v(TAG, (millisUntilFinished % 1000) + " seconds left");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v(TAG, "Finished");
```

Now, I should be getting two **different** log messages at ten seconds. Instead, I only get one. Here is my logCat:

[image]

The arrow indicates where there should have been another log message.

I am lost. I would really appreciate any feedback (positive or negative)! Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said yourself, you could launch both services at the same time.

Or inside the first service, you could pass an `Intent` with some parameters to inform the new amount of time and then call `startService()`.

```
Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
it.putExtra("Time", timeInMillis);
startService(it);
```

I mean, modify your `Service` to get an extra from the calling `Intent`, something like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent != null) {
        long time = intent.getLongExtra("Time",0);
        // Do your ticking here, based on that variable.
    }
    //...
}
```

---

**Edit:** Let's say you want to make your timer run first at 5 seconds, then at 10, 15, and so on.

Once you finish your timer, you could pass the `Intent` to the new `Service`/Timer adding the seconds you want. Like:

```
it.putExtra("Time", timeInMillis + 5000);
```

Comment: When do I put in the extra, because I only want it after 10 seconds. Also, a side note: I was planning on having these messages after more intervals. For example, on 5 and 10 and 15; making new services for each would be a pain. Are there any other ways I can accomplish this? If not, that's okay, just tell me where to put the intents for the code you gave. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think there are lots of ways you could accomplish that behavior... My edit is one of those ways. If you're really using the `Service` class.

Comment: Thanks, I marked you best answer and liked your post!

Answer (score 0):

Use this type.

```
 cdt = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) { //finished on 10 Seconds

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v(TAG, /*"Time remaining " +*/ (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " seconds left"); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v(TAG, "First 10 Seconds Finished"); 

           LoadNextCountdown(); // call the Next Countdown method  

  }
        }
                .start();

//Method for Next Countdown

public void LoadNextCountdown()
{
    cdt2=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) { //finished on 10 Seconds

                @Override
                public void onTick ( long millisUntilFinished){

                    Log.v(TAG, /*"Time remaining " +*/ (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " seconds left");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish () {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Next 10 Seconds Finished");
                }
            } .start();

}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem with this is that the 10 seconds are being counted **after** the initial 20 seconds. My goal is to have the 20 seconds be counted, but after 10 seconds of counting (in the same timer) then display the log. How would I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your log is not displaying because:

```
            if(millisUntilFinished / 10000 == 0){ //TEN SECONDS
                Log.v(TAG, (millisUntilFinished % 1000) + " seconds left");
            }
```

you want it to display when you have 10000 millisUntilFinished but 10000/10000 = 1 not 0.

it should be:

```
     if(millisUntilFinished / 10000 == 1) || if(millisUntilFinished % 10000 == 0)
```

or simply:

```
    if(millisUntilFinished == 10000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have done the last method,  if(millisUntilFinished == 10000). The issue is, countdown timer isn't accurate, so it isn't necessarily going to hit the 10000 mark.